# Add Class Dynamically based on content Jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to dynamically add a class based on the content.

- If `content-wrapper` child has class `cta-content`, `cta-button`, `cta-button` i wanted to add `desc-with-buttons` to `content-wrapper`.
- If `content-wrapper` child has class `cta-content`, `cta-button` add class `desc-with-button`
- If `content-wrapper` child has no `cta-content` and has class `cta-button` add class `no-desc-with-buttons`

Currently only the `no-desc` class is getting added to content wrapper. Please help

```js
$('.cta-wrapper').children().each(function() {
  var getclass = $(this).attr("class");

  if (getclass == "cta-content cta-button cta-button") {
    $(this).parent().addClass('buttons');
  } else if (getclass == "cta-content cta-button") {
    $(this).parent().addClass('button');
  } else if (getclass == "cta-button") {
    $(this).parent().addClass('no-desc');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add Class Content-with-Buttons to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-content"></div>
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class content-with-button to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-content"></div>
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class no-desc-with-button to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by checking length of each `content` and `button` classed element for each `wrapper` like,

```js
$('.cta-wrapper').each(function() {
  var cc=$(this).children('.cta-content').length,
  cb=$(this).children('.cta-button').length,
  cls;
  if(cc && cb>1){
    cls='buttons';
  } else if(cc && cb===1){
    cls='button';
  } else if(!cc && cb){
    cls='no-desc';
  }
  cls && $(this).addClass(cls);
});
```

```css
.buttons{border:1px solid green;}
.button{border:1px solid orange;}
.no-desc{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add Class Content-with-Buttons to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-content">C1</div>
  <div class="cta-button">B1</div>
  <div class="cta-button">B1</div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class content-with-button to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-content">C2</div>
  <div class="cta-button">B2</div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class no-desc-with-button to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-button">B3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `} else if(cc && cb===1){
    cls='button';
  }` is actually not needed

Comment: Here, explanation would be more useful for me and others.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.cta-wrapper').each(function() {
  if ($(this).children().filter('.cta-content').length)
    $(this).children('.cta-button').addClass('.desc-with-button')
  else
    $(this).children('.cta-button').addClass('.no-desc-with-buttons')
})

// Or as custom function

$.fn.addDesc = function(descClass, noDescClass) {
  this.each(function() {
    if ($(this).children().filter('.cta-content').length)
      $(this).children('.cta-button').addClass(descClass)
    else
      $(this).children('.cta-button').addClass(noDescClass)
  })
}

$('.cta-wrapper').addDesc('.desc-with-button', '.no-desc-with-buttons')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  $('.cta-wrapper').each(function()
  {
   var icontent = 0;
   var ibutton = 0;
   $(this).children().each(function(){
    var getclass = $(this).attr("class");
    if (getclass == 'cta-content') {
     icontent = parseInt(icontent) + 1;
    }
    if (getclass == 'cta-button') {
     ibutton = parseInt(ibutton) + 1;
    }
   });
   if (icontent == 1 && ibutton == 2) { 
    $(this).addClass('buttons');
   } else if (icontent == 1 && ibutton == 1) {
     $(this).addClass('button');
   } else if (icontent == 0 && ibutton == 1) {
     $(this).addClass('no-desc');
   }
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Add Class Content-with-Buttons to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-content"></div>
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class content-with-button to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-content"></div>
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
</div>

<!-- Add Class no-desc-with-button to CTA Wrapper -->
<div class="cta-wrapper">
  <div class="cta-button"></div>
</div>
```